# Finding a basis for x+y+z=0

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V \neq \{0\}$ be a vecotspace and for $x,y,z\in V\setminus\{0\}$ is:

$x+y+z=0$

I'd like to find a basis for  $span\{x,y,z\}$

$x=-y-z$ solves the above system for any $y,z$. So we could say $v_1=(2,-1,-1)$ is a basisvector. But we could also do:

$y=-x-z$ and we would get $v_2=(-1,2,-1)$. And of course we could also say, that $v_3=(-1,-1,2)$ is a basisvector.

So $L_1=span\{v_1\}$ or $L_2=span\{v_2\}$ or $L_3=span\{v_3\}$ would span the solution set for $x+y+z=0$.

But what I'm a bit confused about is, that $L_i\neq L_j$ for $i\neq j$. Should we actually get $L_i=L_j$ for any $i,j$?

What's going on here? What's the difference between the $L_i$? I mean I can see that we can basically rotate the coordinates and get the above $L_i$'s but I'm just not really satisfied with this here.

Can someone write me down the transfomration matrix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes no sense. You have $x,y,z\in V\setminus\{0\}$ such that

$x+y+z=0$.

Do you want to compute a basis for $span\{x,y,z\} $ ?

If yes, then observe that $\{x,y,z\} $ is linearly dependent and $x=-y-z$, hence

$span\{x,y,z\}= span\{y,z\}$ .

If $\{y,z\}$ is linearly dependent, then $span\{x,y,z\}= span\{z\}$ and $\{z\}$ is a basis of $span\{x,y,z\} $ .

If $\{y,z\}$ is linearly independent, then $span\{x,y,z\}= span\{y,z\}$ and $\{y,z\}$ is a basis of $span\{x,y,z\} $ .

Comment: What he wants is to find the Kern of a 3x3 matrix filled with ones.

Comment: I'll edit this above. I want to find a basis for  $ span \{x,y,z\}$

Comment: Well, I found a basis for you.

Comment: Thanks, I just solved my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a basis, you seem to make things more complicated than necessary.

> I'd like to find a basis for this.
>
> $x=-y-z$ solves the above system for any $y,z$.

From $\color{blue}{x=-y-z}$, you find that any vector $(\color{blue}{x},y,z) \in V$ is of the form:
$$(\color{blue}{x},y,z) = (\color{blue}{-y-z},y,z) = y(-1,1,0)+z(-1,0,1)$$
meaning that any element can be written as a linear combination of $(-1,1,0)$ and $(-1,0,1)$. Note that these two vectors are linearly independent, thus they form a basis.

Comment: Are you sure? First, I'd have said that $dim span\{x,y,z\}=2$ but the solution says it's 1. They argue with: $y=z=x/2$

Comment: How do you know, that $y,z$ are linearily independent?

Comment: Nevermind, I guess I just solved my confusion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $x+y+z=0$ we can think of
\begin{align}A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and $AX=0$ with $X=(x,y,z)^T$

The basis for nullspace of $A$ is $(1,0,-1)^T$, $(0,1,-1)^T$, so its dimension is $2$.

One can find an orthogonal basis from the  Gram-Schmidt process.